# Deploying Django App to Azure Storage Error

Tags: django, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, python-django-storages

I've been following this tutorial on deploying my django app on Azure: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-azure-app-service/
Everything was working fine until I added Azure storage. Now my webpage is giving me an error saying `Could not find backend 'core.azure_storage.AzureStaticStorage': No module named 'core'` When seeing something like this I instantly thought to check my requirements.txt, they are updated with the required installs (django-storages, azure-core, and azure-storage-blob). At a loss with where to even start here. Re checked the tutorial and all my settings are properly set.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but when I visit my webpage, and receive the error, it says that the error was encountered where I link my static files in my html.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">`

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find backend 'core.azure_storage.AzureStaticStorage': No module named 'core':-

***Need to check below:***

- Firstly, Check the package whether it is installed correctly. If not, Uninstall & re-install the package by executing
  [`pip install azure-storage-blob`](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/)  in the terminal to avoid these kinds of conflicts.
- Check whether the packages installed in the correct environment by running
  `py -m pip freeze`.  It retrieves all the installed packages with their current versions as shown.

[image]

- If you changed any code or configuration, you need to restart your web server or development server by running `python manage.py server`.

*Note:* If still the issue persists, Check the Django version compatibility with the versions of azure-core and azure-storage-blob.

Comment: Inside the server SSH I did a pip install on all 3 of the packages I mentioned in the original post, all three returned that the requirement is already satisfied. Also, I tried resetting server after changes. Still getting the same error message.

Comment: Did you check the version compatibility? @champlooSIXSIX

Comment: Yes, versions seem to be compatible.

Comment: Can you try uninstalling the package and reinstall it?

Comment: Did you try upgrading the pip version also? @champlooSIXSIX

Comment: No, although it does say there is an available update. I can give that a shot.

Comment: Can you try that once?

Comment: Tried upgrading pip, error still persists. Then tried uninstalling and reinstalling the 3 packages from original post, error still being thrown. :'(

Comment: Leave that virtual environment and activate a new one. Can you try in this way?

Comment: I'm operating inside the SSH on my Azure server. I'm not sure if there is a way to activate a new venv.

Comment: Have you installed `pip install azure-core` ? @champlooSIXSIX

Comment: Make sure that this core module is installed in the same django environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253698/discussion-between-champloosixsix-and-jahnavi).